# Flutter align column center

Tags: flutter

I need to achieve the following:

1. Column width fit the content (no wrap if possible)
2. Column is aligned to the center of screen
3. Column's contents are aligned to the left of the Column box

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the `Column` with `Center` widget and `CrossAxisAlignment` to `start` with `MainAxisSize` to `min`.

Example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const [
            Text('This is line one'),
            Text('This is line two'),
            Text('This is line three'),
            Text('This is line four'),
            Text('This is line five'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey.shade400,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [
              Text("Hi there"),
              CircleAvatar(),
              Text("this is a long text"),
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
              Text("vroom x2"),
              SizedBox(
                  width:100,
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator()
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: pic]